# Jupyter Lab starts Intel python processes while ARM python is available

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, apple-m1

I have installed python and jupyter on my MacBook Pro M1Pro. If I start python from my terminal, all is well.

An M1-native ARM process can be seen in the task manager:
[image]

But once I start Jupyter Lab, unfortunately, an Intel process is started:
[image]

Is it possible to "force" jupyter (lab) (installed via Anaconda) to use the ARM executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm honestly not too sure what I did right, but now it works. I installed jupyter via homebrew instead of anaconda and now it launches ARM instances of python... Maybe this will help someone else in the future!